# Is an universal directive implicitly applied on elements?

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular as a beginner. Below is a simple template:

```
 <form class="m-2" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
...
```

I know that `ngSubmit` is a custom event and I also learn that we can create custom event in our own directive with `@Output` decorator as:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "input[myDirective]"
})
export class MyDirective{
   ...
   @Output("mySubmit")
   update = new EventEmitter<string>();
   ...
}
```

then I can use my custom event `(mySubmit)="xxx"` in the template.
since there is no explicit directives used in  element, do my guessing is there is an universal directive implicitly applied on the form element, and this directive defines `ngSubmit`, is my understanding  correct?

Comment: take a look in the docs the type of selectors you can use:https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of, if by universal directive, you mean a directive with a selector which is not limited to an attribute.

You should now, the selector in the directive decorator is simply a CSS selector, so you can apply a certain behavior (via directives) on all sorts of things - for instance, the following directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'button'
})
export class StrongClickDirective {
}
```

will apply to all elements of type button in your application (hence the 'global' behavior you mentioned) - each button will get **it's own instance** of the directive, whether creating such directives is a good practice is a debate on it's own.

Now for `ngSubmit` - if you look at the source code for the [ngForm directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L94) - you can see that the selector (with some exceptions), targets all `form` elements: `form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup]),ng-form,[ngForm]`